# while loop is skipping over my if/else statements

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I have this while loop of a Rock Paper Scissors game and I have if/else if statements that tell you which player won, but the while loop is skipping it and going straight to the end of the loop where it asks if you want to play another game. How would I be able to change this?

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String play = ""; 
        System.out.print("Please enter Play if you want to play the game or anything else to Stop");
        play = scan.nextLine(); 
        
        while (play.equalsIgnoreCase("play")) { 
        System.out.println("Game " + gameCount + " Rock, Paper, Scissors - Play!");
        System.out.print("Choose your weapon [R]ock, [P]aper, or [S]cissors: ");
        String rps = scan.nextLine();
        while (rps.equals('R') || rps.equals('P') || rps.equals('S')) {
            System.out.println("You chose: " + rps);
            
        }
        
        int rand = (int)(Math.random() * 3);
        String myMove = "";
        if(rand == 0) {
            myMove = "Rock";
        }
        else if(rand == 1) {
            myMove = "Paper";
        }
        else {
            myMove = "Scissors";
        }
        System.out.println("I chose: " + myMove);
        
        
        if(rps.equals(myMove)) {
            System.out.println("Tie!");
            tieCount++;
        }
        else if(rps.equals('P') && myMove.equals("Scissors")) {
            System.out.println("Scissors beats paper, a win for me!");
            myCount++;
        }
        else if(rps.equals('S') && myMove.equals("Rock")) {
            System.out.println("Rock beats scissors, a win for me!");
            myCount++;
        }
        else if(rps.equals('R') && myMove.equals("Paper")) {
            System.out.println("Paper beats rock, a win for me!");
            myCount++;
        }
        else if(rps.equals('S') && myMove.equals("Paper")) {
            System.out.println("Scissors beats paper, a win for you!");
            userCount++;
        }
        else if(rps.equals('R') && myMove.equals("Scissors")) {
            System.out.println("Rock beats scissors, a win for you!");
            userCount++;
        }
        else if(rps.equals('S') && myMove.equals("Paper")) {
            System.out.println("Paper beats rock, a win for you!");
            userCount++;
        }
        gameCount++;
        System.out.println("Please enter Play if you want to play the game again or anything else to Stop.");
        play = scan.nextLine();
        
        }   
'''
```

Comment: `rps.equals('S')` => `"S".equals('S')` is `false`. Mind the data types. You probably want `rps.equals("S")`

Comment: I changed it but unfortunately it is giving me the same result. It is still skipping over my if/else if statements

Comment: I think it might be easier if you picked one representation of rock, paper and scissors: having both `"Rock"` and `'R'` is pretty confusing. Pick one or the other, or something like an enum.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
while (true) {
            System.out.println("Insert question code:");
            String question = scanner.nextLine();
            if(question.equals("quit")){
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Insert answer code:");
            String answer = scanner.nextLine();
            if(answer.equals("quit")){
                break;
            }
           
        }
```